# Open a Sqlite connection with an exclusive lock in Java / Scala using SQlite JDBC library

Tags: sqlite, connection, locking

I wish to have read only and write connections for sqlite, when I open a write connection, I wish it to have an exclusive lock.
This looks like it should work

```
val config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.setLockingMode(org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig.LockingMode.EXCLUSIVE)

val connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + this.getPath() +"\\" + this.dbName, config.toProperties)
```

but unfortunately I get an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.BatchUpdateException: batch entry 0: query returns results
```

I have also tried setting the properties directly, rather than using the  Sqlite jdbc SQLiteConfig class

```
val prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("locking_mode", "EXCLUSIVE");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The only way that I was able to personally make it work is by executing a query on the DB itself like this :

```
conn.createStatement().execute("PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE");
```

Comment: Can it be combined with journal_mode=WAL? I get a SQLITE_BUSY error if I try to set both, regardeless of the order